# How to design REST API for aggregate with nested objects?

Tags: rest, reference, aggregate, domain-driven-design, nested-object

I'm designing my first REST-API and am struggling to design the API for a `Cart` aggregate that has nested objects:

```
Cart 1->n SubCart 1->n CartItem.
```

The `Cart` aggregate is saved as a whole. Each time an item is placed in the Cart various discounts have to be calculated that depend on the other `CartItem`s even from other `SubCart`s. Therefore the client app needs to receive a full Cart aggregate with all nested objects.

Evens says in his DDD book that "... The root is the only member of the AGGREGATE that outside objects are allowed to hold references to...".

I understand the general idea, but it is not clear what reference means. Some articles speak about in memory object references, others speak about id references, too. If the user i.e. wants to increase the quantity of an `CartItem` the UI must have a way to identify the item in the cart. It needs to have some ID/reference. Otherwise how shall the `Cart` know what item's quantity should be increased. What did Evans mean with reference? The way it is worded is very confusing.

Since all commands go through the `Cart` aggregate in the backend I wonder if this also should be applied to the REST API. Since I lack the experience I don't know what issues or side effects one or the other solution will have (i.e. caching, security)? Why would one prefer one or the other?

For example for updating the quantity of a `CartItem` I see the following options:

1. `PATCH carts/{id}/subcarts/{subcart_id}/cartitems/{cartitem_id}`.
2. `PATCH carts/{id}/{subcart_id}/{cartitem_id}`.
3. `PATCH /carts/{id}?subcart={subcart_id}&cartitem={cartitem_id}`.
4. `PATCH carts/{id}` having `subcart_id` and `cartitem_id` in the body.

I saw that GIT API used the shorter form of option 2 in some cases. When should one chose option 1 over option 2?

For options 3 and 4 it would be natural to return the new `Cart` object with possible discounts as a result of the `PATCH`.

With option 1 and 2 it seems not RESTful to return a `Cart` object after a `PATCH` of a `CartItem`. The return could be a 204 and the client must then send a `GET` on the `Cart` again, resulting in two calls.

Thanks for any help and insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Even the idea behind it is clear to me, it is not clear what reference means. Some articles speak about in memory object references, others also speak about id references. If the user i.e. wants to increase the quantity of an item the UI must have an id/reference to that item. What did Evans mean with reference?

Pointer.

```
class A {
   B b
}
```

In this example, A "holds a reference to B".  According to Evan's guidelines, if A and B are both domain entities, then either this instance of B is a member of the same AGGREGATE as this instance of A *or* B is itself the root entity of its AGGREGATE.

---

> How to design REST API for aggregate with nested objects?

A REST API is a collection of resources, where resources can be understood to be a generalization of "web pages".  Clients send messages to manipulate resources, and useful business activity is a side effect of manipulate the resources.  See [Webber, 2011](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s).

In other words, the client sends a PATCH/POST/PUT message to the HTTP server, and the server in turn invokes some command(s) on the corresponding aggregate root entity.

```
PATCH /carts/{id}/subcarts/{subcart_id}/cartitems/{cartitem_id}
PATCH /carts/{id}/{subcart_id}/{cartitem_id}
PATCH /carts/{id}?subcart={subcart_id}&cartitem={cartitem_id}
PATCH /carts/{id}
```

All of these are fine, in the sense that you can have as many different resources as you like that change the same aggregate root, and also in the sense that you can use any spelling conventions you like for your resource identifiers.  The only real constraint here is that the identifiers should be RFC 3986 compliant.

Note: keeping all of the client's locally cached copies of different resources synchronized after changes can be tricky; so if you aren't sure you know what you are doing yet, then my suggestion would be to have a single resource per aggregate.

[It is okay to use POST](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post), and you will probably find that sending representations of domain model commands to the server with POST makes the implementation easier than trying to compute a command from a patch document.  Remember, the web was catastrophically successful using HTML forms and POST.

---

> Conseptionally I would favor a single resource for Cart, but how shall the client send a command that updates a sub-resource?

Careful - "sub-resource" isn't really a thing in a REST context.  We have resources, like

```
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986
```

and we have secondary resources, like

```
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.5
```

Neither of those map particularly well to domain entities inside of an aggregate root.  The resource model is a facade in front of the domain model.

In a REST API, the client doesn't interact with the domain model directly.  Instead, the client addresses messages to a resource, and the resource interacts with the domain model (via the aggregate root).

So if you want to show some information to a domain entity buried somewhere in the aggregate "below" the aggregate root, then you send that information to some resource in your resource model, and the message handler in your resource implementation shares that information with the aggregate root, and then the aggregate root shares that information with the other domain entities within the aggregate.

---

> The client needs a full cart to display all changes and I wondered if it is OK to return a cart object from a CartItem resource to avoid two round-trips each time. Would this cause any issues that I'm not aware of?

That will probably be fine if you include the correct metadata in the response.

```
PATCH /carts/1/2/3

...
```

```
200 OK
Content-Location: /carts/1

...
```

It's not really all that different using a POST request that targets a "collection" resource to create a new resource on the server.

That said, if you are sending requests to `/B` to change the representation of `/A`, then you are swimming against the current of the design of the HTTP application, and may want to reconsider.

Comment: Thanks. Conseptionally I would favor a single resource for Cart, but how shall the client send a command that updates a sub-resource? Each change to the cart and it's sub-objects will be a separate command from the client that is executed immediately. There is no save option for the cart. Therefore PATCH would work fine if I would use option 1 or 2. For example wiht CartItems I only have Add, Cancel and ChangeQuantity commands that I can handle with the HTTP verbs using tailored DTOs. It is much more difficult to map all commands from all objects to a single endpoint.

Comment: Thanks again for your detailed response. Sub-resource should have been sub-object. ...Taking the example of updating the quantity of a CartItem my original approach as you also explained was to use a POST against carts/:cartid/:subcartid/:cartitemid, having the new quantity in the body. The handler sends a command to the aggregate root that takes care of it. The client needs a full cart to display all changes and I wondered if it is OK to return a cart object from a CartItem resource to avoid two round-trips each time. Would this cause any issues that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Just to clearify reg. aggregates: As you stated Evans did not mean Id references, but only pointer references. (which makes absolutely sense to me). After I read articles that also advocated avoiding outside id references to nested objects I was confused and it made me wonder if I should not expose URIs for the nested objects at all.

Comment: "Would this cause any issues that I'm not aware of?" see edits.

Comment: "it made me wonder if I should not expose URIs for the nested objects at all."  The vocabulary is a mess - in part because lots of people confuse resources and domain entities.  The thing to notice is that you are introducing coupling here - which can be a form of accidental complexity, making future changes more expensive.  If your domain model is still evolving, then linking directly with domain entities entails a lot more risk.  Doesn't mean it's wrong, but rather that deeper analysis in context is required.

Comment: Yes, I'm setting the Location header of the returned document that holds the representation of the updated cart to the cart resource . ..."That said, if you are sending requests to /B to change the representation of /A, then you are swimming against the current of the design of the HTTP application, and may want to reconsider." ... I don't get what you wanted to explain. If I send a request to /B (i.e. cartItem) it will change the representation of /B and /A (cart). (a Get is only defined on /A.) If addCartItem would be a form the user would be redirected to the updated order, too.

Comment: "The vocabulary is a mess - in part because lots of people confuse resources and domain entities." ... thanks, I'm trying to be more precise. This was not supposed to be a generalization, but should only address the concrete case. I understand that domain entities and resources are different things. My problem was about the details of how to translate between the two. The domain in my case has been stable for 15 years. I'm also the domain expert. The new system is a modern implementation of an older system and adds personalization, but that leads just to extra properties in the model.

Comment: "Get is only defined on /A"  Yes - the fact that you have a resource (/B) that you can edit, but can't read, suggests that you are ignoring the transfer-of-documents-over-a-network domain.  Review Webber 2011 again.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your comment "transfer-of-documents-over-a-network domain". I reviewed Webber, w/o more insight. His order example has no subelements. To clarify, I can't read /B meant I have no resource /B that accepts GET, beacuse the representation of B is returned within the representation of A. B alone has no use in the UI. My UI needs to do: add quantity of items to a subCart of cart, change quantity of an item in a subCart, cancel an item. How would you define the resources and HTTP verbs? I think a concrete solution example would clarify much more for me.

Comment: If your client is reading information from /A, and wants to change that information, then the target URI of the request should be /A.  The choice of PUT vs PATCH vs POST depends primarily on the semantics of the request body.  If the request body is a patch-document, use PATCH.  If the request body is a copy of /A (with some edits) then use PUT.  If the request body is anything else (ex data from an HTML form) use POST.

Comment: Your answer seems to contradict your last edit above. ("PATCH /carts/1/2/3 will probably be fine"). I'm now more confused then before. I.e to change the state of invoiceAddress of an order I can use a Patch against /orders/1 or expose a resouce at /orders/1/invoiceAdresss. The later is what Webber and others advocate. So why can't I expose the subCart or the subItem the same way? Using only Patch on /orders/1 for all different actions (add, remove, cancel, change items, quantity, subcart, invoideAddress, shippingAddress...) makes the server code a mess and the UI not easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to keep it as simple and understandable as you can.

First of all, **REST guidelines are conventions**, not rules written in stone.
Also, you say you are afraid not to be RESTful. I'm almost sure you will not be so anyway :-). For example, I'm almost sure you are not going to implement [HATEOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) at all, and without it you are not creating a RESTful system (like the vast majority of the so-called REST APIs you find around, after all :-))

That said, you should **think in terms of resources and CRUD operations you want to perform on them**.
Since discounts depend on the presence of other items in subcarts, my suggestion is to consider the cart as your resource, including its subcarts and items. This simplifies your work and the overall understanding of the system.

Make your decision based on performance and clarity issues.

Comment: Hi Andrea, thanks for your answer. I'm aware that Hypermedia is a major part of REST. Besides returning links to each sub-object in the returned json I'm looking into HATEOAS for certain parts. I like the idea to keep the interface flexible. Regarding the above options I should better say that option 1 and 2 don't make a pretty interface when a cart object is returned from a CartItem ressource. I'm interested to understand the consequences of each option.